# Set private field value with double brackets initialize

Tags: java, initialization, double, private, brackets

I want to set a value of a private field with double brackets initializer. The next is working

```
Customer customer1 = new Customer();
customer1.setFirstName("Nick");
```

This is also working:

```
Customer customer3 = new Customer("John", "Hammond", true, 80, "3/4/1978");
```

I also want to set the value of the private field with something like this. I know this is not the correct way. Is there any correct way to do this?

```
        Customer customer2 = new Customer()
        {
            {
               firstName = setFirstName("George");
            }
        };
```

Comment: how on earth is that last example supposed to make sense? why does "SetFirstName" start with a capital S?

Comment: @GhostCat ok, and why does he need the Set... call there?

Comment: And unrelated: read about java naming conventions. Method names go camelCase() in java always!

Comment: You cant assign to a private field in a double brace init block. Just say `setFirstName("George")` (without an assignment).

Comment: Worked... Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100120/what-is-this-constructor-call-with-following-double-braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers and I apologise for Pascal Case names on my methods.
The answer is the following (All the fields of my class are public except from firstName which is private):

```
           Customer customer2 = new Customer()
            {
                {
                    setFirstName("Tom");
                    lastName = "Cruz";
                    reliable = true;
                    weight = 70;
                    dateOfBirth = "2/3/1970";
                }
            };
```